# Get z-index of element in TinyMce (orchard)

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, orchardcms

I am using TinyMce4.I have some function that go all over my elements inside editor ,and appends to all elements new div ,AND to that DIV i need set z-index of that (parent)element.

i use draggable on all elements,and when i drag them i can see them one over the other,second element(2) over (3) ,(4) over (1),(2),(3).... than means that they have z-index value some where,but when i debug i cant find it

i used

```
ElementsArr[0].style.zIndex
```

it is return me empty string.

My code:

```
var editor = tinymce.activeEditor; 
var ed_body = $(editor.getBody());
var ElementsArr = tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.select(".draggableTemplate");
var el = ElementsArr[0];
var z = ElementsArr[0].style.zIndex;//z=''
```

In the css z-index is empty ,but when i drag it i can see that they behave like that do have it.

How i can get z-index of this elements,what other way to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(ElementsArr[0]).css('z-index'); // jQuery way
```

or

```
getComputedStyle(ElementsArr[0]).zIndex; // js way
```

Comment: It is returns me z='auto' not number of z-index from each element,but the finny thing that if i set z-index to auto to my new div's it is working :)